# Complex PHP-DI Configuration based on build time variable

Tags: php, dependency-injection, php-di

For my PHP-DI definitions I need to make complex calculations beforhand, which are based on other configurations not coming from PHP-DI (those configurations are stored at build time in a variable). As it is harder to explain, than to show, let me give a simplified example which will show, what I would like to do, but will actually not work.

First let's build the container. The code here is nothing special and shoud work:

```php
<?php

use DI\Container;
use DI\ContainerBuilder;

class MyContainerBuilder
{
    // @param number is the build time (configuration) variable
    // I would like to use later
    public function build(int $number): Container
    {
        $builder = new \DI\ContainerBuilder();
        $builder->addDefinitions(['number' => $number]);
        // In config.php I now want to do some complex calculations
        $builder->addDefinitions(__DIR__ . '/config.php');
        // here the container may be compiled, such that in production, the complex 
        // calculations from `config.php` will only be done once (to my understanding)
        return $builder->build();
    }
}
```

Now comes the problematic part. The calculation in `config.php`

```php
<?php

$number = $container->get('number');
// complex calculation:
$number += 1;

return [
    'improvedNumber' => $number,
];
```

This is of course not possible, since the php-di container seems not to be available in the configuration file. Is it still possible to make the value of `$number` somehow available in the `config.php`?

Sidenote: What I really try to archive is to determine a bunch of services, which shall be injected using php-di. Those services are located in several directories and those directories I must know, when searching for them in the config.php-file.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly your complex calculations involve, but what about simply enabling compilation for php-di and letting it do its magic? In compiled container the variables and function calls are replaced by actual values, so your complex calculation should be only done once during compilation.

Comment: @MichalHynčica Thank You for your comment. The problem I had, when I wrote the question, was not, that I didn't know how to compile the container, but how to inject a value into config.php from where I invoke the compilation of config.php (e.g. here the build function).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this could help but, you can use a factory to achieve that. The factory can take the container as a parameter and then use it to get the ‘number’ value. Here is an example:

```
<?php

use DI\Container;
use DI\ContainerBuilder;

class MyContainerBuilder
{
    public function build(int $number): Container
    {
        $builder = new \DI\ContainerBuilder();
        $builder->addDefinitions(['number' => $number]);
        $builder->addDefinitions([
            'improvedNumber' => function (Container $c) {
                $number = $c->get('number');
                // complex calculation:
                $number += 1;
                return $number;
            },
        ]);
        return $builder->build();
    }
}
```

In this example, the ‘improvedNumber’ service is defined as a factory. When you ask the container for ‘improvedNumber’, it will execute the factory function, which will get the ‘number’ from the container, perform the complex calculation, and then return the result.

This way, you can use the value of ‘number’ in your configuration, even though the container is not available in the configuration file. The factory function is only executed when you ask the container for ‘improvedNumber’, so the complex calculation is only performed once, when ‘improvedNumber’ is first requested.

Comment: Well, I think, that is not what I want. As far as I understand the working of the container, and as You have explained, the improvedNumber calculation is done for every request - as long as there are no other caching mechanisms. What I want is, that the result of the complex calculation is only calculated once for every deployment (in comparison for once for every request), d.i. at compile time of the container. That is how I understand the configuration files. Everything in there (which is not inside a closure) will only be calculated once for every compilation.

Comment: But anyways, good effort and thank You +1.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more research and still not finding a solution, I decided to do it
the ugly way. So **the following works for me, but is a bad solution** in terms of software design. Basically I decided to use a global variable to transfer my build time variable to the php-di configuration script.

```php
<?php

use DI\Container;
use DI\ContainerBuilder;

class MyContainerBuilder
{
    public static int $number;

    // @param number is the build time (configuration) variable
    // I would like to use later
    public function build(int $number): Container
    {
        $builder = new \DI\ContainerBuilder();
        self::$number = $number;
        // In config.php I now want to do some complex calculations
        $builder->addDefinitions(__DIR__ . '/config.php');
        // here the container may be compiled, such that in production, the complex 
        // calculations from `config.php` will only be done once (to my understanding)
        return $builder->build();
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

use MyContainerBuilder;

$number = MyContainerBuilder::$number;

// complex calculation:
$number += 1;

return [
    'improvedNumber' => $number,
];
```

This is a bad solution, since it couples the php-di configuration file with
MyContainerBuilder in a rather obscure way and of course this may lead to all
Problems one has with Services using static fields/methods. Also one has to keep
in mind, that one cannot rely on the code working, when creating multiple
containers using `MyContainerBuilder::build`, although the latter is unlikely to
happen (Yeah, how could that possibly happen ...).